# Type conversion SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, oop, frameworks

I'm trying to load classes from a framework dynamically but the application crashes with conversion sending SIGABRT signal:

```
let newClassType = NSClassFromString("MyFramework.CustomClass") as! BaseClass.Type
```

With classes declared in MyApp it works fine as well as with framework's classes but without conversion.

BaseClass.swift (MyApp.xcodeproj and copied to MyFramework):

```
public class BaseClass{
...
}
```

CustomClass.swift(MyFramework.xcodeproj):

```
public class CustomClass: BaseClass{
...
}
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Then how it comes that a subclass declared identically to CustomClass but within the project has it if this is the issue?

Comment: NVM, my previous comment was wrong. The more obvious issue, which I missed earlier, is that `NSClassFromString` only works for `@objc` types, since only those types are registered and known to the ObjectiveC runtime

Comment: Have you tried changing `as! BaseClass.Type` to `as! MyFramework.BaseClass.Type`? Or have you confirmed that `NSClassFromString("MyFramework.CustomClass")` is not nil?

Comment: Changing to MyFramework.BaseClass.Type did work, however since it treats MyApp.BaseClass and MyFramework.BaseClass as different classes I'm not able to  use new classes anywhere where MyApp.BaseClass is required. I understand that coping .swift files with parent classes to framework project isn't a good idea. So how do I resolve this appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

From The question and the comments I suggest to use `typealias`

```
import MyFramework

typealias FrameworkBaseClass = MyFramework.BaseClass
typealias FrameworkCustomClass = MyFramework.CustomClass
```

Then if you want to use `FrameworkBaseClass`, `FrameworkCustomClass` in other `.swift` files, you do not have to import `MyFramework`